# Edited Address Not showing in invoice in magento...!

Tags: php, magento

I updated my store address to new address.

I follow below steps:

`Step1:Go to System ->> Configuration
Step2:Click on the “General” button in the left side menu pane
Step3:Click on the “Store Information” and fill in the Store Name, Store Contact Telephone, and Store contact Address
Step4:Click “Save Config”`

But the new address is not displaying in the invoice.
It's showing the old address.

So how to update the new address?

Comment: riya.. go to `system->configuration->shipping settings` and change your store address from there..

Comment: nope its not working....!! now also its showing old address..!!
is there any cache clear system in Magento??

Comment: yes.. `system->cache management` select all and than refresh

Comment: Its not working still showing old address.

For Example in Invoice on top right corner Address is Syndney australia

I want display new address i.e Delhi India..!!
But it still showing Sydney Australia..!!!

Comment: have you `rebuild indexes` and re-run the `compilation process`??

Comment: bt it will delete any data..??

Comment: bt how to rebuild index??
i have no idea of what it is? & how to do it..!!!

Comment: for compilation `system->tools->compilation`.. for indexing `system->index management`...